# Visual Studio 2010 is prompting to login to Team Foundation Server

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Visual Studio 2010 is prompting to login to a Team Foundation Server. How can I remove this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

If you go to `Tools:Options:Source Control`, you can change your `Current source control plugin` to something else (or nothing).

Comment: i try your solution but when i reopen VS it is still there.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are being prompted to make a TFS connection to a CodePlex TFS server.

If this is a result of opening a .sln, then you can cancel, and try disassociating this .sln with any source control. Unbind from source control.

Perhaps within Team Explorer you've got a TFS entry there to that CodePlex server. Try disconnecting that.